# Bash CLI that accepts multiple arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix, while-loop, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a custom CLI & I ran into a problem.

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function definations.
__help_menu() {

      echo -e ""
      echo -e "======================="
      echo -e "THESE ARE THE AVAILABLE COMMANDS:"
      echo -e ""
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh --create -domain example.com"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh --create -domain example.com -ssl <no|yes>"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh --create -domain example.com -ssl <yes|no> -wp <yes|no>"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh --delete -domain example.com"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh --delete -domain example.com -ssl <yes|no>"
      echo -e "======================="
      echo -e ""
}

__create() {

    # Do something. I got this.
    echo -e "I got this"
}

__delete() {

    # Do something. I got this.
    echo -e "I got this"
}

__cli() {

    # Run while loop.
    while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
        case $1 in
            --create)
                shift
                case $1 in
                    -domain) 
                        DOMAIN_NAME="$2"; 
                        shift 
                        ;;
                    -ssl)
                        INSTALL_SSL="$2"; 
                        shift 
                        ;;
                    -wp|--wp) 
                        INSTALL_WP="$2"; 
                        shift 
                        ;;
                    *)
                    echo -e "Unknown parameter passed: $1";
                    __help_menu
                    exit
                    ;;
                esac
                ;;
            --delete)
                shift
                case $1 in
                    -domain) 
                        DOMAIN_NAME="$2"; 
                        shift 
                        ;;
                    -ssl)
                        DELETE_SSL="$2"; 
                        shift 
                        ;;
                    *)
                    echo -e "Unknown parameter passed: $1";
                    __help_menu
                    exit
                    ;;
                esac
                ;;
            --help) __help_menu; exit ;;
        *) echo -e "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; exit 1 ;;
        
        esac
        shift
    done
}

__cli "$@"

if [ "$1" == "--create" ]; then

    echo -e "Command is to create a new site."
    echo -e "Domain name: $DOMAIN_NAME"
    echo -e "Install SSL: $INSTALL_SSL"
    echo -e "Install WP: $INSTALL_WP"
    echo -e ""
fi
```

When I run `./cli.sh --create -domain example.com` it's working fine. But when I run `./cli.sh --create -domain example.com -ssl yes` it says Unknown parameter passed: -ssl. Where am I doing a mistake?

Another question:

What is the best way to replace `./cli.sh --create -domain hello.com` with `foo --create -domain hello.com` so I can use the CLI from anywhere in the terminal.

Comment: You parse `--create` and `-domain` arguments and then come to `case` with `$1 == -ssl`.
This code can take only one `-` argument after `--` arg.
You can things easier by having `domain` as the first argument with no dashes. Also take a look at [getopts](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/getopts.1.asp)

Comment: You need more than one loop. You need the outer loop for the command and two inner loops for the options of each command. It may be easier to put the command in the end: `cli [options] <command>`.

Comment: Cringe; why do you litter your code with unnecessary `echo -e`? Use `printf` (or here, simply `cat` a here document) just to reduce the smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example how to use GNU `getopt` to simplify command line parsing:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

options=$(getopt -q -o '' -l domain:,ssl:,wp: -- "$@") || {
  printf 'ERROR: Invalid argument\n' >&2
  exit 1
}
eval set -- "$options"

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    --domain) DOMAIN="$2"; shift 2;;
    --ssl)    SSL="$2";    shift 2;;
    --wp)     WP="$2";     shift 2;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *)  break;;
  esac
done

COMMAND=$1; shift

case ${COMMAND:?missing} in
  create|delete)
    echo "$COMMAND" "${DOMAIN:?missing}" "${SSL:-yes}" "${WP:-yes}";;
  *)
    printf 'COMMAND: invalid\n' >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

Usage:

```
./cli.sh create --domain http://example.com
```

The default for `--ssl` and `--wp` is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

@ceving

I think I got what I was looking for. I'll explore the `getopt` command more. I made a simple tweak. It works.

```
#!/bin/bash

__help_menu() {

      echo -e ""
      echo -e "======================="
      echo -e "THESE ARE THE AVAILABLE COMMANDS:"
      echo -e ""
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh create --domain example.com"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh create --domain example.com --ssl <no|yes>"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh create --domain example.com --ssl <yes|no> --wp <yes|no>"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh delete --domain example.com"
      echo -e "⟹   ./cli.sh delete --domain example.com --ssl <yes|no>"
      echo -e "======================="
      echo -e ""
}

__handle_create () {

    if [ "$COMMAND" = "create" ]; then

        if [ "$SSL" = "no" ] && [ "$WP" = "no" ]; then
            __create $DOMAIN
        else
           INSTALL_SSL=$SSL
           INSTALL_WP=$WP   
            __create $DOMAIN $INSTALL_SSL $INSTALL_WP
        fi 
    fi
}

__create() {

    echo -e ""
    if [ "$DOMAIN" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "DOMAIN is: $DOMAIN"
    fi
    if [ "$SSL" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "INSTALL SSL: $INSTALL_SSL"
    fi
    if [ "$WP" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "INSTALL WP: $INSTALL_WP"
    fi
    echo -e ""
}

__handle_delete() {

    if [ "$COMMAND" = "delete" ]; then

        if [ "$SSL" = "no" ]; then
            __delete $DOMAIN
        else
            __delete $DOMAIN $SSL
        fi 
    fi
}

__delete() {

    echo -e ""
    echo -e "DOMAIN is: $DOMAIN"
    echo -e "DELETE SSL: $SSL"
    echo -e ""
}

__cli() {

    options=$(getopt -q -o '' -l domain:,ssl:,wp: -- "$@") || {

    echo -e 'ERROR: Invalid argument\n' >&2
    exit 1
    }

    eval set -- "$options"

    while true; do
    case "$1" in
        --domain) DOMAIN="$2"; shift 2;;
        --ssl)    SSL="$2";    shift 2;;
        --wp)     WP="$2";     shift 2;;
        --) shift; break;;
        *)  break;;
    esac
    done

    COMMAND=$1; shift

    case ${COMMAND:?missing} in
        create )
            __handle_create $@
            ;;
        delete )
            handle_delete $@
            ;;
        help )
            __help_menu
            ;;
        *)
        __help_menu
        ;;
    esac
}

__cli "$@"
```

BTW, in order to replace `./cli.sh create --domain example.com` with `foo create --domain example.com` should I add an Alias that points to `./cli.sh` file or is there a better way?

Comment: Rename it to `foo` and put it in a directory, which is in the `PATH` environment. If you use the program only yourself, create the directory `$HOME/bin`, put it there. If other users should use the program, put it in `/usr/local/bin`. Do not use an alias, because an alias can not be used in another script. Aliases are for interactive use only.

Comment: Thank you again.